# How to save data dynamically for R package?

Tags: r, function, r-package

I want to save dynamic data or dataframe (because it depends on parameters) inside a function and want to use this saved data another function. I thought of using saveRDS(), but since I work in my local, I didn't know if it would work when I made it public. I don't get any errors, warnings or notes when I check, but I'm looking for a better solution.

```
get_data <- function(startDate,endDate){
  
  df <- ... # dynamic
  
  saveRDS(df,"df.rds")
  
}

funcx <- function(){
  
  df2 <- readRDS("df.rds")
  
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On option could be to save data in `tempdir()`, if that data does not need to persist after usage of your functions; maybe you can clarify.

Comment: is there a reason you can't return `df` in `get_data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** As mentioned in the comments just pass the data using the return value of the first function and arguments of the second.

```
get_data <- function(startDate, endDate) {
  data.frame(startDate, endDate)
}

funcx <- function(df){
  print(df)
}

get_data(1, 2) |> funcx()
```

or store the data in your workspace and then get it from there:

```
Data <- get_data(1, 2)
funcx(Data)
```

or put it in an option

```
options(Data = get_data(1, 2))
funcx(getOption("Data"))
```

**2)** Use a local environment:

```
e <- local({
  df <- NULL
  get_data <- function(startDate, endDate) {
    df <<- data.frame(startDate, endDate)
  }
  funcx <- function(){
    print(df)
  }
  environment()
})

e$get_data(1, 2)
e$funcx()
```

or put the environment right in the package.  Look at `lattice.options`  and `lattice.getOption` source code in the lattice package for an example of this where it uses the .LatticeEnv environment that is stored right in the package itself.

```
library(lattice)
ls(lattice:::.LatticeEnv)
lattice.options # displays source code of lattice.options
lattice.getOption # displays source code
```

**3)** The proto package can be used to clean up (2) a bit.  proto objects are environments having their own methods.  See the package vignette and help files.

```
library(proto)

p <- proto(
      get_data = function(., startDate, endDate) {
        .$df <- data.frame(startDate, endDate)
      },
      funcx = function(.) {
        print(.$df)
      }
)
p$get_data(1, 2)
p$funcx()
```