# assign() versus '<-' assignment operator

Tags: r

I have a package called 'mypkg' with this top-level code:

```
#' @export
myenv <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
```

When I use the package, I can set value with 'assign' func

```
> assign('foo', 'bar', mypkg::myenv)
```

But why can't I set value with the '<-' operator ?

```
> mypkg::myenv$foo <- 'bar'
Error in mypkg::myenv$foo <- "bar" :
  object 'mypkg' not found
```

Comment: The `::`-operator is a function that expects an existing package name and a function name. It’s designed to retrieve a function object. It doesn’t name sense that you would be able to use assignment into a package from the console.

Comment: @IRTFM I see: the '::' operator has been designed to be used with a func on the RHS, not an environment. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically because  `assign` accepts an environment argument.   `<-`  expects variable names (only) for the assignee.
Quoting from the man page  , i.e.

```
?`<-`
```

"The operators <- and = assign into the environment in which they are evaluated."

If you want to assign a variable in a different environment, you thus have to use `assign`  or other function which accepts an environment reference.
EDIT:  as suggested by IRTFM,  `utils::assignInNamespace` might be a simpler approach.  Sadly, `?assign` man page doesn't include that func in the "See Also" section.

Comment: The OP might benefit from being referred to the `assignInNamespace` function.

Comment: I'm not sure that you do see. You would need to have a `::<-` function and no such function exists.

Comment: The high level: The first function to get evaluated was ordinary `<-` and it tried to find its first argument and failed

Comment: “`<-` expects variable names (only) for the assignee” — This isn’t correct. R supports complex expressions as the assignee. Otherwise we couldn’t perform subset assignment, and replacement functions wouldn’t exist. It’s just that `::<-` *specifically* isn’t defined, and *can’t* be defined given R’s current semantics (since it’s performing NSE and its LHS does not name a local variable).

Comment: @KonradRudolph is correct:  `<-` accepts almost anything that is found ** in the current environment**

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do a "complex assignment".  As the manual says in section 3.4.4, `mypkg::myenv$foo <- 'bar'` is equivalent to these three lines:

```
`*tmp*` <- mypkg
mypkg <- `::<-`(`*tmp*`, value = `$<-`(mypkg::myenv, foo, "bar"))
rm(`*tmp*`)
```

Things go wrong on the very first line, because `mypkg` isn't an object that has a value that can be assigned.  If it was, it would die on the second line, because there's no `::<-` function defined.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the link to documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to create set and get function in mypkg that have access to myenv. (We could optionally export only those two functions but not myenv and require that the user use those two functions to access myenv effectively encapsulating myenv.) Below we create and install mypkg reproducibly and then test out these functions.

Another example of this is in the lattice package.  See [How to save data dynamically for R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73259792/how-to-save-data-dynamically-for-r-package/73260006#73260006)

```
library(devtools)
library(pkgKitten)

# create mypkg package
kitten("mypkg")
cat("myenv <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
set_myenv <- function(x, value) myenv[[x]] <- value
get_myenv <- function(x) myenv[[x]]", file = "mypkg/R/Rcode.R")
install("mypkg")

# test
library(mypkg)
set_myenv("foo", "bar")
get_myenv("foo")
[1] "bar"
```

Comment: Indeed, exposing function instead of variable is a nice way to circumvent this issue. Thanks for the code example !