# How to change state of a package exported variable from a package function?

Tags: r, package

### Reproducible example:

Inspired from [Hadley book on pacakges](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#sec-data-state):

Create a new empty package called `test` with `NAMESPACE` file:

```
## file NAMESPACE
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

And an R file `R/package_var.R`:

```
## file R/package_var.R
var <- 0

change_var <- function() {
var <<- 1
}
```

Then build the package.

---

Now if you test the package in a new R session:

```
> library(test)
> var
0
> change_var()
Error in change_var() : 
cannot change value of locked binding for 'var'
```

---

But right after this example Hadley states:

> you can’t change the binding for objects in the package namespace (well, at least **not without trying harder than this**).

What is the hard way Hadley is talking about?

Comment: You have just missed what Hadly said. He stated later in the chapter that you should use an environment to bind your variable if you want to change that variable. Just continue reading for several lines, you will find that. Try adding lines of `the <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())` and `the$var <- 0`.

Comment: You cannot change a variable binding to the environment of a package. And I do think you have read that lines because the sentence you quote is under the same error you have found.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76599995/assign-versus-assignment-operator/76600761#76600761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use the `unlockBinding` function as noted in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331690/modify-package-function/58238931#58238931):

```
change_var <- function() {
  unlockBinding("var", as.environment("package:test"))
  assign("var", 2, as.environment("package:test"))
}
```